# SQL Server Query Failing

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have 2 servers Server A and Server B. They both have SQL Server 2016 SP2-CU7 installed with 64 GB memory and same amount of disk space for Temp DB. I allocated same amount of memory for both servers (48 GB).

When I run a script it fails on Server A with this error:

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140737993048064' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

But on Server B it runs in 3 minutes without any issues. I requested more space for TempDb drive on Server A but the script still fails.

How can I find out what is wrong with Server A?

Comment: You need to find out what is making tempDB grow so much.  I would use sp_WhoIsActive to see what is happening on the server.  And look here for a great script to track tempDB usage: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13911/how-to-find-the-sql-statements-that-caused-tempdb-growth

Comment: No one else is active on both servers. It's just me who is running the same script across both servers.

Comment: What are your autogrowth settings on Server A and Server B?

Comment: I ended up tuning the query by creating some indexes on some of the tables and I was able to make it run on Server B. I will look at the auto growth settings.